# Camera not following the player after spawn

Tags: unity, c#, camera

After my character spawns, the camera just stays in the same place. How can I solve that?

Here's my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SideScrolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform mario;

    private void Start ()
    {
        mario = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    }


    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 cameraPosition = transform.position; 
        cameraPosition.x = Mathf.Max(cameraPosition.x, mario.position.x);
        transform.position = cameraPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console window? And are you moving your character to the left or right? Do you notice this issue from the beginning of the scene, or only after the character has respawned?

Comment: theres no errors, the character respawns like normal but the camera stays in place

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cameraPosition.x = Mathf.Max(cameraPosition.x, mario.position.x);
```

To

```
cameraPosition.x = mario.position.x;
```

Look at the following code

```
Vector3 cameraPosition = transform.position; 
cameraPosition.x = Mathf.Max(cameraPosition.x, mario.position.x);
transform.position = cameraPosition;
```

If `cameraPosition.x` >= `mario.position.x`, then the camera won't move if mario is moving toward negative X direction, because `Mathf.Max(cameraPosition.x, mario.position.x)` would return the value of `cameraPosition.x`.